# Automation test In hybrid application

Tags: java, android, selenium

I'm doing automation testing with appium,  selenium and junit in android device. My native application has some hyperlink and I need to verify web content after clicking on each link. But selenium can't switch driver like this(from remote driver to web driver). Is there any way to do this ? Or any tool, framework instead of using selenium, appium can handle this task ? Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you saying that you click a link and it opens a new window? The "from remote driver to web driver" line is confusing me, RemoteDriver is a WebDriver.

Comment: @Mark Rowlands For example: In a normal native application like "skype", It has a hyperlink then when I click on a link it will open a browser with the URL.

Comment: So you have a list of links and when you click on a link it opens a new window*?  *whatever its called on Android. If that's the case, you just need to use the `.switchTo().window();` method.

Comment: @ Mark Rowlands the problem is the link is in application, not in the browser.

Comment: Right, sorry I follow now. Unfortunately, the only way I would know to do this is to copy the URL from your app, rather than clicking on it, and pasting the URL into a `driver.get(url)` call. Obviously this wouldn't test the actual functionality of opening a browser from your app though.